# Diffenrece between an setval and alter sequence restart command

Tags: postgresql

To set value of a sequence to a value

these both command same to have the same result

```
SELECT setval('lcm.samplings_id_seq', 1, false); 

ALTER SEQUENCE lcm.samplings_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

but to do an alter sequence you seem to need to be owner...
for the other one, update grant on sequence seem ok.

is there any other reason to use alter sequence for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) on `ALTER SEQUENCE`:

> In contrast to a setval call, a RESTART operation on a sequence is
>   transactional and blocks concurrent transactions from obtaining
>   numbers from the same sequence. If that's not the desired mode of
>   operation, setval should be used.

If you're looking to block any usage of the sequence while you are performing the update, then you want to go with the `ALTER SEQUENCE` method. If you just need to reset the counter and are fine with other transactions using the sequence, then you can use your first example using `setval`.